# Find missing element in an array

Tags: c#

I've an array consisting english letter a to z except one letter. I dont know which element is missing and I need to find that element using only one loop. I cant use if statements and inbuilt functions.

Is it really possible?. I got this question in an exam and couldn't find any solution and its eating my brain. Any insights appreciated.

```
// missing 'h'
var letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];

for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
 // find missing letter in 1 loop with no if statements or built-in functions 
}
```

Comment: Is it javascript or c#?

Comment: I can use either javascript or c#

Comment: Does the array have an empty character? Can you use it compared to another array (e.g. the actual alphabet)? You need to have something to cross check.

Comment: It doesn't contain any empty character. No i cant compare it with another array

Comment: can you use stuff like .toString() or .toChar()?

Comment: Is the array sorted?

Comment: toString() is inbuilt function right so I think no

Comment: If you give each number a value from 1 to 25 and then total all the number. The total for all 25 would be 325. Then then missing one is 325 - total.

Comment: Yup the array is sorted

Comment: @jdweng that makes sense

Comment: What does "can't use any conditions" even mean? Your for loop will have a condition underneath. Does that mean you can't write any if statements yourself?

Comment: @sam  u r right I cant use if statements. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Optimus What class was this? Context of course material might give us clues as to how your professor may have wanted you to answer this

Comment: @mhodges actually the I got this question on our annual competency exam in my company

Comment: @jdweng He said there is no empty string in the array. Which means your way won't work. Am I thinking it wrong?

Comment: @jdweng The idea is right, but I don't think the implementation with the given restrictions is possible. You would somehow have to know which characters map to which numbers. You could do this very easily with char codes, but that uses a built-in

Comment: The array is 25 numbers (not 26).  So adding 25 number and subtracting from the expect total will give index of the missing number.

Comment: @mhodges: Obviously you never read "The C Language" by K & R.  Loaded with ways of indexing characters like my solution below.

Comment: @jdweng Yeah, i was reading this as a JS question. I have since removed the tag since it cannot be done with JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code :

```
             char[] inputs = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };

             int total = 0;
             foreach (char c in inputs)
             {
                 total += (int)c - (int)'a';
             }
             char missingChar = (char)((int)('a') + (325 - total));

             // version 2
             total = 0;
             //from sum of a arithmetic sequence for even number of values
             // for example 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = (1 + 4) + (2 + 3) = 2 * 5 = 10
             int expectedTotal = 13 * ((int)'a' + (int)'z');
             foreach (char c in inputs)
             {
                total += (int)c;
             }
             missingChar = (char)((expectedTotal - total));
```

Comment: Super creative solution

Comment: I didn't event this.  Learned it ages ago.  The trick of programming is learning algorithms, remembering the algorithms, then applying algorithms to current programming task.

Comment: I added a version 2 of the code which is even simpler than original.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Program
{
    private static void FindLetter(string[] alphabet, string[] yourMissingLetter)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < yourMissingLetter.Length; i++)
        {
            var isit = alphabet[i] == yourMissingLetter[i];
            Console.WriteLine("alphabet[{0}] = {1}", alphabet[i], isit);
        } 
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] alphabet = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
        // let's say your array is missing B
        string[] yourMissingLetterArray = { "A", "C", "D" };
        FindLetter(alphabet, yourMissingLetterArray);
    }
}
```

not as brilliant as the actual answer but this will work:

The moment it starts missing the letter will turn false and the index will show you which letter it is.

Comment: This only works if the array is sorted.  The actual answer work if the array is not sorted.

Comment: @jdweng they asked the guy if the array is sorted and he said yes. So this works.

Comment: Did you test your code?  How many print statements does your code output?

Comment: @jdweng Assuming it would be the whole alphabet it would print 26 and once you've reached the false, you'd look at the index and find which letter it is. or vice versa. To answer your question, now it prints 3 times.

Comment: And what letters does it say that it is missing?

Comment: @jdweng alphabet[A] = True
alphabet[B] = False It's missing B. I just copy pasted and ran my own code.

Comment: You get same message all three times?

Comment: @jdweng Oh I see. What you mean. No, anything after that will return false, but the question was if you can spot one letter missing. So, it does spot one letter missing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it without using any loop just list functions(Console Application) it also take care of lower upper case comparison issue:

```
namespace MissingAlphbetLetters
{
    class Program
    {

        public static List<char>  CheckDifferences(char[] str)
        {
            List<char> alphabet= new List<char>(new char[]
            { 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'});
            List<char> compaired = str.ToList().ConvertAll(l => char.ToLower(l));
            List<char> difference = new List<char>();
            if (str.Length > 0)
            {
                difference = alphabet.Except(compaired).ToList();
            }
            return difference;
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Join(",",CheckDifferences(new char[]     { 'A', 'g', 't', 'h', 'o', 'm', 'd', 'e' })));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```